# Why am getting a name error in google colab?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, keras-layer

After importing `convo2d` from `keras.layers`, I am getting a `NameError`.

```
NameError                                 
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-65-0f76ad089d1e> in <module>()
      3 
      4 #add first layer
----> 5 model.add( Convo2D(32, (5,5), activation='relu', input_shape=(32,32,3)))
      6 
      7 #add a pooling layer

NameError: name 'Convo2D' is not defined
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper name is `Conv2D`, not `Convo2D`.

Comment: thanks (*-*)  i just found out after 1 hour of scrolling and searches  ---  but worth informative